# insertRow JavaScript not recognized

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript but still tend to try fixing an issue myself. However, I got frustrated because the same function works for a slightly different HTML without **tbody** and **thead**.

The error I get is --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null.

Where am I wrong? Also probably there is a better way to add a table row? I tried **.append** but it did not work for me.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped myTable">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="addTableRow">Add table row</button>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr id="firstRow">
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Morgan</td>
            <td>mail@mail.com</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>09.12.14</td>
            <td>04:17 a.m.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#addTableRow").click( function(){

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

cell1.innerHTML = "Text-1";
cell2.innerHTML = "Text-2";
cell3.innerHTML = "Text-3";
cell4.innerHTML = "Text-4";
cell5.innerHTML = "Text-5";
cell6.innerHTML = "Text-6";

});
```

Comment: You've defined `myTable` as a class. Change your table tag to `<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">`

Comment: @Papa Thank you! My fault really. :/ But if I put insertRow (-1); it says Unexpected token ILLEGAL. As I have read it should put the row as the last one, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few typos, missing ID on your table and mixing jQuery incorrectly.

```js
$("#addTableRow").click( function () {      
  var row = $("<tr>");

  row.append($("<td>Text-1</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-2</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-3</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-4</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-5</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-6</td>"))
     .append($("<td>Text-7</td>"));
 
  $("#myTable tbody").append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped myTable">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="addTableRow">Add table row</button>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr id="firstRow">
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Morgan</td>
                    <td>mail@mail.com</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td>09.12.14</td>
                    <td>04:17 a.m.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Not strictly related to the question, but I ended up here for having the "Uncaught TypeError: table.insertRow is not a function" error. You may be having the same problem. If so:

If you want to use

```
row.insertCell(0);
```

and you receive the former error, be sure not to get the element by using jquery:

DO NOT

```
let table = $("#peopleTable");
let newRow = table.insertRow(0);
```

DO

```
let table = document.getElementById("peopleTable");
let newRow = table.insertRow(0);
```

Comment: .insertRow does not work on a jquery-fetched table, that is right.